# How to delete cookies after overriding native cookie functions?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

It's possible to override the document.cookie setter and getter using a script like this one:

```
if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor && Object.defineProperty) {
  var cookieDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'cookie') || Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLDocument.prototype, 'cookie');
  if (cookieDescriptor && cookieDescriptor.configurable) {
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
      get: function() {
        return cookieDescriptor.get.apply(document);
      },
      set: function(value) {
        //do your own stuff before setting the cookie
        cookieDescriptor.set.apply(document, value);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

With this cookie proxy, we need to filter the cookies and allow the good ones to be set. Some marketing scripts injected via Google Tag Manager are pretty much uncontrollable and, instead of removing those scripts, we want to prevent/block the unknown/undesired cookies they set to be created. This script allows us to do that; however, cookies set via HTTP Response, that are not into the welcome-list, should also be removed and, that's the problem.

After using the script above, we can't delete a cookie anymore through the expiration date.

So, this sort of cookie removal technique does not work anymore:

```
document.cookie = "cookieTest=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
```

**Is there any workaround to make cookie deletion work when the native functions are overridden?**

Comment: Maybe you could run a function with `setInterval()` that periodically removes unwanted cookies.

Comment: I don't think there's any hook into the built-in cookie processing from HTTP responses.

Comment: And I don't think any of this will be able to detect HttpOnly cookies.

Comment: Neither do I, but as soon as Http cookie is set the cookie is reachable via document.cookie and, it could be deleted, however, we can't because of the "hack" thing I mentioned. Those are not really preventable, but "deletable" at least if the deletion worked.

Comment: Your code could check the expiration time that's being set. If it's in the past, it's a cookie deletion, so it should allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listener service such as ListenLayer. They have a browser storage listener. You can tell it the cookie names you want it to listen for and it will parse the cookies and push them into the dataLayer object whenever they are set/changed, or anytime the page loads and they exist.
[In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiXZ4.png) you can see I am telling the listener to focus on the _ga and _hstc

When the listener pushes the cookie data into dataLayer, you can write a simple rule inside the platform to trigger off the dataLayer push and store something in the browser. You can basically use this to override the cookies with either a single space or a text string like DELETED
[Here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMT3V.png) I have a browser storage rule that triggers whenever I have a data layer event called nativeCookie (which comes from when the Listener sees the cookies set from my first image).

When that condition is met, [here in image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X53Pg.png) you can see I am setting each cookie to have a single empty space with a long expiration. Now the cookies will still exist, but they will be empty for a very long time. The listneer is set to re-push the data layer event if they ever change again, and they will be changed back to a " ".

In this case, GA constantly tries to keep setting their cookie ID, they must be using some sort of fingerprinting or they recognize that it is an empty value.  The solution works though: the listener just keeps replacing the cookie with a " ". You could experiment and try null and see how it behaves, it might depend on the services you are trying to block and how they set their cookies.